# Quickly gives warnings on packaging, not recognizing setup.py~

Tags: packaging, quickly

I have been trying to make an application and package it and so on, but I have run into a lot of errors, so I'm trying to get back to basics:

After the command `quickly create ubuntu-application dj1` and `cd dj1` I get my app, which can run and package with `quickly package`, works fine!

I get some warnings that

```
** (setup.py:5609): WARNING **: 
Error sending credentials: 
Error sending message: Operation not permitted
```

but I've read that one should state your name and such in the `setup.py` file at the bottom. So I did `quickly edit` and had to open the `setup.py` file separately and wrote my license, name, email, description and long description at the appropriate places (I did not include a web page). I saved and terminated gedit.

Now when I run `quickly package` I get

```
....... 
Command returned some WARNINGS:
---------------------------------- 
WARNING: the following files are not recognized by DistUtilsExtra.auto:
  setup.py~
----------------------------------
Do you want to continue (this is not safe!)? y/[n]: n
```

I've read on this forum that one can downgrade `python-distutils-extra` to the last stable version with:

```
sudo apt-get install python-distutils-extra=2.32-2
```

but after I did that and tried to package again I got the same warnings. (and I also read that one should not simply remove the `setup.py~` file)

Does anybody know how to get rid of these warnings? Am I using the editor wrongly? I tried before and used emacs, but same thing there...

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever editing program you used to change `setup.py` created a backup `setup.py~` of the original file. When the program is packaged by distutils, file types that it doesn't recognize (i.e. the .py~) give a warning. Just delete the file. Not sure how to turn off that behavior in whatever editor you're using.

**EDIT**: In gedit you can turn off automatic backups by going to Edit->Preferences->Editor tab and unchecking 'Create a backup copy of files before saving'

Comment: This time, I used gedit (the default editor for "quickly edit") but I've also used Emacs, with the same result...

Comment: I edited the answer to show how to turn off this feature in gedit.